# Wait for a function to finish multiple resource calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm kind of newbie to AngularJS and struggling with the promise API. I've implemented a `save()` function in my controller in order to get:

1. The regulation version saved
2. Once the regulation version is saved, all of its installation types are saved in an async-parallel way
3. The `saved!` log displayed after everything is done (in my real application I want to go to other application state here)

That's the code I currently have in my controller:

```
var saveRegulationInstallationTypes = function (result) {
    var saveOperations = [];
    angular.forEach(vm.installationTypeRegs, function (
            installationTypeReg, key) {
        installationTypeReg.regulationVersion = result;
        var res = InstallationTypeReg.update(installationTypeReg, function () {
                console.log('Installation type updated');
            });
        saveOperations.push(res);
    });
    return $q.all(saveOperations);
}

function save() {
    var regulationVersionSaved = RegulationVersion.update(vm.regulationVersion);
    return regulationVersionSaved.$promise.then(
        function (result) {
            saveRegulationInstallationTypes(result).then(console.log('saved!'));
    });
}
```

`RegulationVersion` and `InstallationTypeReg` are services returning `$resource` methods for each of the http operations over the entities. The problem when executing the save() method is that I get the `saved!` log before the `Installation type updated` ones. I guess, as I'm returning `q.all` from my function, it should wait to finish all the inner operations before calling the callback.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems two issues: 1) "saveOperations.push(res);" -- should be "saveOperations.push(res.$promise);"  -- As in the array it should store the promise not whole object. and 2) saveRegulationInstallationTypes(result).then(console.log('saved!')); should be saveRegulationInstallationTypes(result).then(function(){console.log('saved!')});

Comment: It makes sense, but even if I change it to store the promise, the logging order keeps being the same.

Comment: Try with below change:

 "saveRegulationInstallationTypes(result).then(console.log('saved!'));" 
to 
"saveRegulationInstallationTypes(result).then(function(){console.log('saved!')});"

Comment: Yeah, this with your answer makes the trick. Please, edit and add this comment to the answer. Thanks!